# project program error that I cannot figure out at all

Tags: java, debugging

The compiler keeps saying there is an error down at my if else statement and I cannot figure out why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PackingOrganizer{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int cartons = 4, boxes = 5;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of items : (All partial items are to be rounded up. ex. 6.5 items is rounded to 7 items)");
        double itemcount = input.nextDouble();

        if (itemcount != (int) itemcount);
            System.out.println("Invalid input round all partial numbers up");
        else if (itemcount % cartons = 0){
              int containerAmount =( itemcount \ cartons );
              System.out.println("Cartons can be used. The" + itemcount + " items will require " + containeramount + " cartons. ");}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error massage you see?

Comment: remove the semicolon after the if statement

Comment: I removed the semicolon it still does not work though. the else if statement is red. it says unexpected type required variable found value

Comment: You should really put braces around the if and else blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several errors actually:

- a semicolon right after if clause
- `\` is not a division symbol, `/` is the one
- `itemcount` is `double`, and dividing it by an `int` we get `double`, but `containerAmount` is declared `int`
- `itemcount % cartons = 0` is not a valid boolean expression, you probably wanted `itemcount % cartons == 0`
- a typo: `containerAmount` is declared, but `containeramount` is referenced

An advice: try using some syntax highlighting and dynamically compiling IDE. I can recommend [eclipse](http://eclipse.org) or [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

Comment: I have erased it and it still doesn't work

Comment: @JimJANES: "doesn't work" tells us little that we can use to help you. What *new* errors or problems are you seeing? Can you post the latest code? Please help us help you.

Comment: Ok thanks for adding more info. It seems like it will work now thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You need some changes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int cartons = 4, boxes = 5;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of items : (All partial items are to be rounded up. ex. 6.5 items is rounded to 7 items)");
    double itemcount = input.nextDouble();

    if (itemcount != (int) itemcount) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input round all partial numbers up");
    } else if (itemcount % cartons == 0) {
        int containerAmount = (int) (itemcount / cartons);
        System.out.println("Cartons can be used. The" + itemcount + " items will require " + containerAmount+ " cartons. ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `;` right after your `if (itemcount != (int) itemcount)`. This means that `if` your conditional is true, nothing will be done, and then `System.out.println("Invalid input round all partial numbers up");` would always be executed. However there is also an `else` which now cannot find the iff that it is attached to because your `if` has two statements after it and no curly braces (`{}`). To avoid these kinds of errors, I recommend always using curly braces like this:

```
if (itemcount != (int) itemcount) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input round all partial numbers up");
}
...
```

That can help you avoid these kinds of compile failures.